# Python - Remove all sub-strings not in list

Tags: python, string, pandas

I want to remove all sub-strings within a df column that aren't present in a defined list. For example:

```
mylist = {good, like, bad, hated, terrible, liked}

Current:                                         Desired:
index      content                               index        content                                          
0          a very good idea, I like it           0            good like
1          was the bad thing to do               1            bad
2          I hated it, it was terrible           2            hated terrible
...                                              ...
k          Why do you think she liked it         k            liked
```

I've managed to define a function which keeps all words not in the list, however dont know how to invert this function to achieve what I want:

```
pat = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(mylist))
df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.contains(pat, '')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['column1'] = df['content'].str.findall('(' + pat + ')').str.join(' ')
print (df)
                         content         column1
0    a very good idea, I like it       good like
1        was the bad thing to do             bad
2    I hated it, it was terrible  hated terrible
3  Why do you think she liked it           liked
```

Or list comprehension with split, filtering and join:

```
df['column1'] = df['content'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([y for y in x.split() if y in mylist]))
print (df)
                         content         column1
0    a very good idea, I like it       good like
1        was the bad thing to do             bad
2    I hated it, it was terrible  hated terrible
3  Why do you think she liked it           liked
```